# Solr Grouping with multifield facets

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to know if this is possible using **solr query**:

1. Two columns to consider: location1, location2
2. Want to do a face on both the columns.

Below query will work:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/? q=*:*&version=2.2&rows=0&facet=true&facet.field=location1&facet.field=location2
```

**Response:**

```
    <response>
        <lst name="responseHeader">
            <int name="status">0</int>
            <int name="QTime">13</int>
        </lst>
        <result name="response" numFound="7789" start="0"/>
        <lst name="facet_counts">
        <lst name="facet_queries"/>
        <lst name="facet_fields">
        <lst name="location1">
            <int name="Chicago">100</int>
            <int name="NewYork">50</int>
            <int name="Washington">30</int>
        </lst>
        <lst name="location2">
            <int name="Washington">200</int>
            <int name="Philadelphia">100</int>
            <int name="Chicago">50</int>
        </lst>
<response>
```

What I need, is to group both location1 and location2 and get the following results:

```
Washington  :230
Chicago     :50
Philadelphia:100
Washington  :30
```

Currently we do it at the service layer. But can this be done using result grouping in solr? What I understand is result grouping gives an aggregate of all the data but goes not do a facet topic aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Solr does not [support Grouping on Multivalued](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) fields.

```
Support for grouping on a multi-valued field has not yet been implemented.
```

You can probably create a new field at indexing with a combined value and use the fields for faceting.

EDIT :- 
Use a copy field to copy the contents of both fields to a single field and perform facet on it. Need just the schema changes and reindexing of data

Comment: Thanks Jayendra! But for me Location1 and Location2 are not multivalued fields.Can I get those computed results?

Comment: if it is not multivalued fields then how are you faceting on it ?

Comment: They are 2 different fields, location 1 and location 2. I both fields are part of facet search. somthing like this : facet.field=location1&facet.field=location2

Comment: use a copy field to copy the contents of both fields to a single field and perform facet on it. Need just the schema changes and reindexing of data

Comment: update: Grouped faceting supports single and multivalued fields. Default is false. Solr4.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to store both `location1` and `location2` in a single multi-valued field, say `locations`. Then you can issue this facet query to get what you want:

```
q=*:*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.field=locations
```

Comment: there is no way to group these 2 fields apart from doing at service layer? say parse the json and group it with custom code?